# finding characters between symbols in string

Tags: java, regex

There is a given string which contains host:port sequences and the trouble is to compare a fully qualified host name and a short one. That is they should be equal.

Example: "`hostName:1234,hostname.sg.com:3214,otherHost:1458`".
Here `hostName` and `hostname.sg.com` should be equal.
The question is how to find characters between "`hostName`" and ":" sign?
I tried `.+(:)` but, of course, it selects everything until last ":".

Comment: Try `(?i)hostName[^:]*` or even (a string literal) `"(?i)\\bhostName[^:]*"`

Comment: Guava has a nice MapSplitter for that (`Splitter.on(',').withKeyValueSeparator(':').split("hostName:1234,hostname.sg.com:3214,otherHost:1458.")`), see https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the found characters, i.e. do you want to split or extract them etc.? One way to fix _your_ expression (although I'm not sure it fits your needs due to missing information on how you use it) might be to make it reluctant: `.+?(:)`.

Comment: basically I want to extract that piece I found

Comment: Trying to solve this with a single regex is unreasonable.  It might be possible, but it will likely be obfuscated and obscure.  Do yourself a favor and [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) the string, then place the [canonical host names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName--) in a Set (or make them keys in a Map).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
(?<=hostName).*?:
```

This will just check if there are chars after the `hostName` to the *closest* `:`, without including `hostName` in the match.